# onClick function parameter containing "."

Tags: javascript, php, html, parameters, onclick

I'm trying to create a table that contains an onClick function for the items in the Change Password column of the table, so that my system administrator can change everyone's password.

Each onClick calls the function "ChangePassOpen", which opens a modal with the new password entry box and another button to actually call the function to change the password.

In order for my program to identify what account the admin is changing I need to pass the username as a parameter, however my usernames contain "." as they are comprised of a forename and surname, like "T.Smyth". This, however, causes an error because the program thinks I'm trying to pass two paramters, so it throws an error.

Any ideas of how to overcome this?

```
    <?php
//Retrieves variables from Javascript.
$Search = $_POST["Search"];
$Type = $_POST["Type"];

if ($Type == "Registration Date"){
    $Type = "joined";
}
else if ($Type == "Account Rank"){
    $Type = "rank";
}

include "db/openlogindb.php";
if($DBError == true){
    $data = 3;
}
else{

    $UserSearch = "SELECT username, surname, forename, joined, rank FROM users 
    WHERE ".$Type." LIKE '%".$Search."%' 
    ORDER BY surname";

    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $UserSearch);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($results) == 0){
        $data = 1;
    }
    else{
        $data = '';

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){ 
            $data .= '<tr><td>'.$row['surname'].'</td><td>'.$row['forename'].'</td><td>'.$row['username'].'</td><td>'.$row['joined'].'</td><td>'.$row['rank'].'</td><td onClick="ChangePassOpen('.$row['username'].')">Change Password</td></tr>';
        }
    }
}

include "db/closelogindb.php";

echo $data;
?>
```

http://thomas-smyth.co.uk/admin/manageusers.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: How would I use this in the context of my program? I have no issues currently with the SQL other than the fact that the usernames retrieved don't work as parameters.

Comment: I think `'</td><td onClick="ChangePassOpen('.$row['username'].')">` should be `'</td><td onClick="ChangePassOpen(\''.$row['username'].'\')">`

Comment: Apologies, it didn't seem to copy and paste as I intended. The code boxes here are quite glitchy.

Comment: Perfect! That worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes I realised it when I formatted your code and the brackets split on that statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your code

```
echo '<table><tr><td>'.$row['surname'].'</td><td>'.$row['forename'].'</td><td>'.$row['username'].'</td><td>'.$row['joined'].'</td><td>'.$row['rank'].'</td><td onClick="ChangePassOpen(\''.$row["username"].'\')">Change Password</td></tr></table>';
```

A backslash character () is considered to be an escape character.

Comment: Hmmmm - as commented. Now it cannot be closed as typo